# How to set width of ListView divider?

Tags: android, listview, width, divider

How can I set the width of my custom ListView divider, in order to have it smaller than my row width?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a 9 patch png that has transparent pixels on the left and right. For example, a 53x4 .9.png that has 25 transparent pixels either side (+ pixels to 9patch it) would stretch the 1 pixel out so there is 25 pixels either side of it.

Answer (score 62):

*A `RecyclerView` is generally preferred over using a `ListView` now. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434248/how-to-indent-the-divider-in-a-linear-layout-recyclerview-ie-add-padding-marg) for how to set the width of the divider in a `RecyclerView`.*

## Use `<inset>`

drawable/list_divider.xml

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="10dp"
    android:insetRight="10dp" >

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/list_divider_color" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

And in your layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```

[image]

**Sources:**

- [Listview divider margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096304/listview-divider-margin)
- [How to assign padding to Listview item divider line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054364/how-to-assign-padding-to-listview-item-divider-line)

Comment: I tried this. But it overlays my custom divider on the default one. Any idea why?

Comment: @Suragch sorry for offtopic, but I didn't find any mention in documentation regarding `ListView` deprecation. I understand your thought behind these words, but I think it could confuse somebody. Nevertheless, great answer.

Comment: elegant, simple, does the job. thkx

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to make 9 patch, then you can insert

`<View
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
         android:background="#33B5E5" />`

in your xml code of list_item. It creates a blue line and you can easily control the width of this line.
To make this successful you would have to disable the divider of the listview . Which is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602672/black-lines-between-listitems-how-to-erase-them)

Comment: Leave `width` at `match_parent` and set a left or right margin.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call

[mListView.setDivider(Drawable d);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

And pass it a drawable that you can include in your res/drawable folders. If you want to make it go almost all the way across you could just make a 9 patch that contains a horizontal line with as much transparency on the left and right sides as you want. And set it to stretch the middle portion of the line.