# Black lines between listItems,how to erase them?

Tags: android

There are some horizontal black lines between my list items.How can i erase them?
There are not part of my graphics.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    listview.setDivider(null);
    listview.setDividerHeight(0);
```

**or in XML**

```
   <ListView
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use property [dividerHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3adividerHeight). Just set it to 0dp.