# Margin of ListView row is not visible

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, margin

I have a ListView with custom row style with rounded coreners. I want to set a margin for ListView rows. but when I'm trying to set margins of rows, nothing is visible to me.
This is my row style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/orange" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="@color/bright_orange"
        android:startColor="@color/bright_orange" />

</shape>
```

this is rows layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_row_style"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How should I set the margin between ListView rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play with some attributes of your list view like dividerHeight. You can find more information on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16768738/693752).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` as parent for `rows layout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

use `padding` in `LinearLayout` instead of `margin`

replace this

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

with (updated)

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this   `rounded_edge.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"   >

<solid
    android:color="#fdfdfd" >
</solid>

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#dedede" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp">
</padding>

<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" 
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp">
</corners>

</shape>
```

And in ListView put this line

```
  android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
```

Comment: I don't need padding, I just need margins between rows.

Answer (score 0):

use this tag in listview in xml:

```
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
```

check this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight