# Assign padding to ListView item divider line

Tags: android, listview, divider

I want to assign padding to `ListView` item divider line, and i used inset but it didn't work. why?

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/aboutList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
  android:dividerHeight="0.3dp"/>
```

list_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="15dp"
    android:insetRight="15dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/dividerColor"/>
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054364/how-to-assign-padding-to-listview-item-divider-line

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding and divider like this.

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/aboutList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:padding_left="15"
  android:padding_right="15"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:divider="@color/dividerColor"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

With your code updating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="15dp"
    android:insetRight="15dp">

    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@color/dividerColor"/>
        <corners android:radius="2.0dip" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

you have set divider height too thin add `minimun 1px.`

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/aboutList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
  android:dividerHeight="1px"/>
  //android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```