# Drawable Divider in a Listview fills parent

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have this image:

[image]

and I want to assign this image to the divider property of a listview. The problem is the image expand all the width, and when I execute this app in a device the image is two horizontal lines, instead of two points.

This my XML code:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_list_view"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />
```

Here's my 9.png:

[image]

Comment: You cannot set the width of the list divider.

Comment: Yeah, I know. So how I can be the divider property an image and not deformed horizontally?

Comment: I think you have to make nine patch image . Repeat image after your Dot.....

Comment: have a look at this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider

Comment: have a look at this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010072/how-to-set-width-of-listview-divider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure i never tired it, but a possible idea, try to make a 9patch image from your image with extra transparency, at let the system stretch the invisible part of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Its is not possible to change the width of list divider because its flow is manage by os framework.