# Simple Android RecyclerView example

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've made a list of items a few times using Android's `RecyclerView`, but it is a rather complicated process. Going through one of the numerous tutorials online works ([this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-recyclerview-example), [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView), and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k) are good), but I am looking a bare bones example that I can copy and paste to get up and running quickly. Only the following features are necessary:

- Vertical layout
- A single TextView on each row
- Responds to click events

Because I have wished for this several times, I finally decided to make the answer below for my future reference and yours.

Comment: check this [tutorial with source code](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/12/android-recyclerview-with-cardview.html)

Comment: For future guys, here I have written a detailed article with video tutorial
https://handyopinion.com/how-to-show-vertical-list-in-kotlin-using-recyclerview-example/

Comment: https://youtu.be/UZwiKdrm768: You can checkout this video tutorial as it explains in detail about the recyclerview:

Comment: check this gist ..
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/-RecyclerView

Answer (score 600, accepted):

The following is a minimal example that will look like the following image.

[image: RecyclerView with a list of animal names]

Start with an empty activity. You will perform the following tasks to add the RecyclerView. All you need to do is copy and paste the code in each section. Later you can customize it to fit your needs.

- Add dependencies to gradle
- Add the xml layout files for the activity and for the RecyclerView row
- Make the RecyclerView adapter
- Initialize the RecyclerView in your activity

## Update Gradle dependencies

Make sure the following dependencies are in your app `gradle.build` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

You can update the version numbers to whatever is [the most current](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39239240/3681880). Use `compile` rather than `implementation` if you are still using Android Studio 2.x.

## Create activity layout

Add the `RecyclerView` to your xml layout.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAnimals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Create row layout

Each row in our `RecyclerView` is only going to have a single `TextView`. Create a new layout resource file.

*recyclerview_row.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Create the adapter

The `RecyclerView` needs an adapter to populate the views in each row with your data. Create a new java file.

*MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java*

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Notes

- Although not strictly necessary, I included the functionality for listening for click events on the rows. This was available in the old `ListViews` and is a common need. You can remove this code if you don't need it.

## Initialize RecyclerView in Activity

Add the following code to your main activity.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with
        ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
        animalNames.add("Horse");
        animalNames.add("Cow");
        animalNames.add("Camel");
        animalNames.add("Sheep");
        animalNames.add("Goat");

        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Notes

- Notice that the activity implements the `ItemClickListener` that we defined in our adapter. This allows us to handle row click events in `onItemClick`.

## Finished

That's it. You should be able to run your project now and get something similar to the image at the top.

## Going on

**Adding a divider between rows**

You can add a simple divider like this

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
    layoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

If you want something a little more complex, see the following answers:

- [How to add dividers and spaces between items in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618829/how-to-add-dividers-and-spaces-between-items-in-recyclerview)
- [How to indent the divider in a linear layout RecyclerView (ie, add padding, margin, or an inset only to the ItemDecoration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434248/how-to-indent-the-divider-in-a-linear-layout-recyclerview-ie-add-padding-marg)

**Changing row color on click**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704439/3681880) for how to change the background color and add the Ripple Effect when a row is clicked.

[image: Insert single item]

**Updating rows**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959184/3681880) for how to add, remove, and update rows.

[image: Insert single item]

## Further reading

- [CodePath](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)
- [YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k)
- [Android RecyclerView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viWlr.png) (stacktips tutorial)
- [RecyclerView in Android: Tutorial](http://www.androiddeft.com/2017/10/01/recyclerview-android/)

Comment: Very nice.  THis works until I add a button and try to set its click listener.  Any ideas why that might interfere?

Comment: @johnktejik, it is hard to know exactly what you are talking about from the information you provide here. This would probably best be asked as a new question. My guess is that your button is handling the motion event so that other things don't get it.

Comment: sorry.. to add description of animal?  EX: Camel in new TextView: is animal  // Sheep in new TextVire : is animal. I need help.. T_T

Comment: @Suragch thank you for the tutorial, Does it also work for horizontal output?

Comment: @coder, You're welcome. Yes, I've used this for horizontal output and it works the same.

Comment: If you get an error when using the constructor go into the adapter file and append `public` in front of the constructor so that it can be used outside the package.

Comment: Other solution wihout interface https://hackernoon.com/android-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-getadapterposition-a-better-way-3c789baab4db

Comment: OnClick for item, makes code really hard for use, usage for radio buttons always returns error, to make code work, is really a lot of job

Comment: i have error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"

Comment: This answer needs some updating to androidx.

Comment: @JoseAlcérreca, I'm mainly working on Flutter now so I haven't been keeping my Android answers up to date. You have my permission to update the code if you would be willing to make the update (preferably testing that it works).

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the whole point of RecyclerView to not have to manually implement the ViewHolder pattern? This is just as much code as a ListView with view holders, so whats the advantage?

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing, in a ListView using view holders is a good idea. In RecyclerView it's required. This has the advantage of making it harder to mess up. (P.S. I use Flutter now. It is soooooo much easier to [make a ListView](https://pusher.com/tutorials/flutter-listviews). Waaaay less code. I'm very happy not to be messing with Android ListViews and RecyclerViews any more.)

Comment: onItemClick takes 4 values not 2 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: Thanks for the above.....additionally what I am looking for is an example where I can implement the same with dagger2....mostly the examples I am getting involves API call and using the same to populate the list. But in your case, you are forming the arraylist from the activity itself. Is there a way i can inject the Animals class using dagger and break the dependency?

Comment: @I haven't used dagger and I'm a little out of the loop with Android activities now since I've moved on to Flutter. Sorry.

Comment: You can get context from parent of onCreateViewHolder save your line by adding this view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_products, parent, false);

Comment: For androidX ---- implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

Comment: 7 years later and with a few minor import statement adjustments, this still works.  Google needs to work on simplifying android development -- it's incredibly complex to do trivial tasks as compared to visual studio.

Comment: @kevincw01, Well, in a way Google did simplify Android development when it created Flutter. In Flutter, ListViews are MUCH simple to create. I'll never go back to native Android development to make Android apps. I don't miss it at all.

Comment: I blame @Suragch for my late night researching flutter tonight :)

Comment: @kevincw01, heh heh, well worth your time. Especially if you decide you also want to publish your app for iOS. Or Linux. Or Windows. Or Mac. Or Web. When my Android app became popular, people requested an iOS version. It took a year of learning and work to become comfortable with iOS development. But then every app I made needed two versions. And every update needed twice the amount of work. Now I build once with Flutter and deploy on both Android and iOS with minimal effort. It's not even a contest. Even if I was only focusing on Android, though, I would still use Flutter.

Answer (score 22):

### Minimal Recycler view ready to use Kotlin template for:

- Vertical layout
- A single TextView on each row
- Responds to click events (Single and LongPress)

I know this is an old thread and so answer here. Adding this answer for future reference:

Add Recycle view in Build dependency

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
    // RecyclerView
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
```

Add a recycle view in your layout

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/wifiList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />
```

Create a layout to display list items (list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/ssid"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Now create a minimal Adapter to hold data, code here is self-explanatory

```
 class WifiAdapter(private val wifiList: ArrayList<ScanResult>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WifiAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

     // holder class to hold reference
    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        //get view reference
        var ssid: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.ssid) as TextView
    }

     override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
         // create view holder to hold reference
         return ViewHolder( LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))
     }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //set values
        holder.ssid.text =  wifiList[position].SSID
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return wifiList.size
    }
      // update your data
     fun updateData(scanResult: ArrayList<ScanResult>) {
         wifiList.clear()
         notifyDataSetChanged()
         wifiList.addAll(scanResult)
         notifyDataSetChanged()

     }
 }
```

Add this class to handle Single click and long click events on List Items

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, RecyclerView recyclerView, int position);

    }
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child,recyclerView,  recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
```

Lastly Set your adapter to Recycler View and add Touch Listener to start intercepting touch event for a single or double tap on list items

```
    wifiAdapter = WifiAdapter(ArrayList())

    wifiList.apply {
        // vertical layout
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        // set adapter
        adapter = wifiAdapter

        // Touch handling
        wifiList.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerTouchListener(applicationContext, wifiList, object : RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "RV OnCLickj " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onLongClick(view: View, recyclerView: RecyclerView, position: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "RV OnLongCLickj " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        ))
    }
```

**Bonus**: Update Data

```
wifiAdapter.updateData(mScanResults as ArrayList<ScanResult>)
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason `RecyclerTouchListener` is written in Java?

Answer (score 18):

## ***This will be the simplest version of the implementation of RecyclerView.***

[image]

#### activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

#### list_item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### CustomAdapter.java

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private List<String> data;
  public CustomAdapter (List<String> data){
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Override
  public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(rowItem);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position));
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return this.data.size();
  }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
      super(view);
      view.setOnClickListener(this);
      this.textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position : " + getLayoutPosition() + " text : " + this.textView.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(generateData()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
  }

  private List<String> generateData() {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      data.add(String.valueOf(i) + "th Element");
    }
    return data;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

[image: Android RecyclerView]

Start by adding recyclerview library.

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Create model class.

```
     public class UserModel implements Serializable {

    private String userName;


    public UserModel(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
   }
```

create adapter class.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersAdapterVh> implements Filterable {

    private List<UserModel> userModelList;
    private List<UserModel> getUserModelListFiltered;
    private Context context;
    private SelectedUser selectedUser;

    public UsersAdapter(List<UserModel> userModelList,SelectedUser selectedUser) {
        this.userModelList = userModelList;
        this.getUserModelListFiltered = userModelList;
        this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsersAdapter.UsersAdapterVh onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();

        return new UsersAdapterVh(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users,null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.UsersAdapterVh holder, int position) {

        UserModel userModel = userModelList.get(position);

        String username = userModel.getUserName();
        String prefix = userModel.getUserName().substring(0,1);

        holder.tvUsername.setText(username);
        holder.tvPrefix.setText(prefix);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userModelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if(charSequence == null | charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = getUserModelListFiltered.size();
                    filterResults.values = getUserModelListFiltered;

                }else{
                    String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                    List<UserModel> resultData = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(UserModel userModel: getUserModelListFiltered){
                        if(userModel.getUserName().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)){
                            resultData.add(userModel);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                    filterResults.values = resultData;

                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

                userModelList = (List<UserModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }


    public interface SelectedUser{

        void selectedUser(UserModel userModel);

    }

    public class UsersAdapterVh extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvPrefix;
        TextView tvUsername;
        ImageView imIcon;
        public UsersAdapterVh(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvPrefix = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prefix);
            tvUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            imIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    selectedUser.selectedUser(userModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

create layout row_uses.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/users_bg"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prefix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/headerColor"
                android:text="T"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/headerColor"
            android:text="username"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Find recyclerview and populate data.

```
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

List<UserModel> userModelList = new ArrayList<>();

String[] names = {"Richard","Alice","Hannah","David"};

UsersAdapter usersAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    for(String s:names){
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel(s);

        userModelList.add(userModel);
    }

    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(userModelList,this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

}
```

find full tutorial and source code here:

[Android RecyclerView](https://youtu.be/ujKDN_ZtGHQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Comment: Why you send context to user adapter class  `usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(userModelList,this);` ?.

Comment: @OmarBoshra ```this``` refers to the implementation of the ```SelectedUser``` interface.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a much newer Kotlin solution for this which is much simpler than many of the answers written here, it uses anonymous class.

```
val items = mutableListOf<String>()

inner class ItemHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var textField: TextView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    rvitems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    rvitems.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder {
            return ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.textField.text = items[position]
            holder.textField.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I took the liberty to use **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** as it's simpler. I wanted to simplify it even further and put ItemHolder as an inner class but couldn't quite figure out how to reference it in a type in the outer class parameter.

Comment: I nearly quit kotlin and android development, because there were no simple solutions, until I saw yours. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  And how do you respond to clicks?

Comment: @SMBiggs What do you mean? The code for handling clicks is also present within this example inside onBindViewHolder.

Comment: I see it now--my bad.  I somehow skipped that part of the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: This seems nice but what exactly is this code supposed to be a part of?  Where does `rvitems` come from?

Comment: Ah I'm guessing it's supposed to be inside a fragment?  I adapted your answer into a complete activity here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74215835/851699

Answer (score 5):

To get started , just to view something in Recycler view

recycler view adapter can be something like this.

```
class CustomAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var data =  listOf<String>()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    override fun getItemCount() =data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txt.text= data[position]
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        )
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val txt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view)
    }
}
```

and to attach the adapter to the recycler view and to attach data to adapter

```
val view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)                                              
val adapter = CustomAdapter()                                                                          
val data = listOf("text1", "text2", "text3")
adapter.data = data                                                                             
view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
view.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Incomplete... does not show `item_text_view.xml` or `item_view.xml`

Answer (score 4):

Based on different sources I have created Simple Implementation of RecyclerView using a Simple Library.

Add this line in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.hereshem.lib:awesomelib:2.0.1'
```

AddCreate a RecyclerView by adding MyRecyclerView in activity_main.xml with

```
<com.hereshem.lib.recycler.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now in the MainActivity, Create a ViewHolder by passing the name of Class that needs to bind

```
public static class EVHolder extends MyViewHolder<Events> {
    TextView date, title, summary;
    public EVHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        summary = v.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(Events c) {
        date.setText(c.date);
        title.setText(c.title);
        summary.setText(c.summary);
    }
}
```

Create Items list variable and adapters with very few lines by passing items, class and layout in the adapter

```
List<Events> items = new ArrayList<>();
MyRecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, items, EVHolder.class, R.layout.row_event);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ClickListener can be added with following lines

```
recycler.setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recycler Item Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Its all done.

More example and implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/hereshem/Easy-RecyclerView-Library) .
Hope this helps !!!

Comment: what is single activity

Comment: : error: cannot find symbol
        summary = v.findViewById(R.id.summary);
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable summary
  location: class id
EVHolder.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
EVHolder.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        date.setText(c.date);

Comment: @johnktejik R.id.summary is the id given for layout resource file.
please see this layout file https://github.com/hereshem/Easy-RecyclerView-Library/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/row_event.xml

Answer (score 3):

**Dependencies**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.lguipeng.bubbleview:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

**One Class For Click Item**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }


}
```

**Second Class RecyclerView**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SLByTopics extends Fragment {


    public static ArrayList<MByTopics> byTopicsMainArrayList=new ArrayList<>();


    TabRefreshReceiver tabRefreshReceiver;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SAdpByTopics sAdpByTopics;
    public ArrayList<MByTopics> mByTopicsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public SLByTopics(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sl_fragment_by_topics, container, false);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        if (IsOnline.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            getCategoryTree();
        } else{
            IsOnline.showNoInterNetMessage(getActivity());
        }
        tabRefreshReceiver = new TabRefreshReceiver();
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(tabRefreshReceiver, new IntentFilter("BY_TOPICS"));

        setUpView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setUpView(View view) {

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.by_topics_list_recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                if (mByTopicsArrayList.get(position).getChild().size()>0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SByTopicCategory.class);
                    intent.putExtra("selectedCategoryName",mByTopicsArrayList.get(position).getCatname());
                    intent.putExtra("jsonData",mByTopicsArrayList.get(position).getMainTopicJson());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SByCategoryQuestionList.class);
                    intent.putExtra("selectedSubCategoryName",mByTopicsArrayList.get(position).getCatname());
                    intent.putExtra("catID",mByTopicsArrayList.get(position).getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
                }
            }
        }));

    }

    private class TabRefreshReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(SLByTopics.this).attach(SLByTopics.this).commit();
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(tabRefreshReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void getCategoryTree() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Const.HOSTNAME + Const.STUDENT_GET_CATEGORY_TREE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            String status = object.getString("status");
                            int i = Integer.parseInt(status);

                            switch (i) {

                                case 0:
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
//                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "getCategorySuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("getCategoryTree Response", "getCategoryTree Response : " + response);

                                    try {    
                                        byTopicsMainArrayList.clear();
                                        JSONArray info = object.getJSONArray("info");
                                        if (info.length() > 0) {
                                            for (i = 0; i < info.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject data = info.getJSONObject(i);
                                                MByTopics mByTopics = new MByTopics();
                                                mByTopics.setId(data.getString("id"));
                                                mByTopics.setCatname(data.getString("catname"));
                                                mByTopics.setMainTopicJson(data.toString());

                                                JSONArray topicChildren = data.getJSONArray("children");
                                                ArrayList<SMByTopicCategory> byChildrenArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                                                for (int j = 0; j < topicChildren.length(); j++) {
                                                    JSONObject topicChildrenData = topicChildren.getJSONObject(j);
                                                    SMByTopicCategory smByTopicCategory = new SMByTopicCategory();
                                                    smByTopicCategory.setId(topicChildrenData.getString("id"));
                                                    smByTopicCategory.setCatname(topicChildrenData.getString("catname"));
                                                    smByTopicCategory.setChildTopicJson(topicChildrenData.toString());

                                                    JSONArray topicChildrenQuestion = topicChildrenData.getJSONArray("children");
                                                    ArrayList<SMByTopicSubCategory> byChildrenSubArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                                                    for (int k = 0; k < topicChildrenQuestion.length(); k++) {
                                                        JSONObject topicChildrenSubData = topicChildrenQuestion.getJSONObject(k);
                                                        SMByTopicSubCategory smByTopicSubCategory = new SMByTopicSubCategory();
                                                        smByTopicSubCategory.setId(topicChildrenSubData.getString("id"));
                                                        smByTopicSubCategory.setCatname(topicChildrenSubData.getString("catname"));
                                                        smByTopicSubCategory.setChildSubTopicJson(topicChildrenSubData.toString());

                                                        byChildrenSubArrayList.add(smByTopicSubCategory);
                                                    }

                                                    smByTopicCategory.setQuestions(byChildrenSubArrayList);

                                                    byChildrenArrayList.add(smByTopicCategory);
                                                }
                                                mByTopics.setChild(byChildrenArrayList);
                                                byTopicsMainArrayList.add(mByTopics);
                                            }


                                            mByTopicsArrayList.clear();
                                            mByTopicsArrayList=byTopicsMainArrayList;
                                            sAdpByTopics=new SAdpByTopics(mByTopicsArrayList,getActivity());
                                            recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdpByTopics);
                                            sAdpByTopics.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        }

                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
//                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "getCategoryError : " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("getCategoryTree Not Response", "getCategoryTree Uploading Not Response : " + response);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("getCategoryTree Error :","getCategoryTree Error :"+error.getMessage());
//                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){

        };/* {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                map.put("uid", String.valueOf(ConfigManager.getUserId()));
                return map;
            }
        };*/

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class For Recycler Item**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SAdpByTopics extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<MByTopics> topicsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        Activity activity;

     public SAdpByTopics(ArrayList<MByTopics> topicsArrayList,Activity activity){
        this.topicsArrayList=topicsArrayList;
        this.activity=activity;
     }

     @Override
     public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemeView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_by_topic_list,parent,false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder=new Holder(itemeView);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        return holder;
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         final Holder classHolder = (Holder) holder;
         try{
             classHolder.txt_topic_name.setText(topicsArrayList.get(position).getCatname());
         }catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
        return topicsArrayList.size();
     }


class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txt_topic_name;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt_topic_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
}
```

**Module Class**

```
public class MByTopics {

    String id;
    String topicName;
    String catname;
    String MainTopicJson;
    ArrayList<SMByTopicCategory> child;
    ArrayList<SMByTopicSubCategory> questions;

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return  id;
    }

    public void setCatname(String catname) {
        this.catname = catname;
    }

    public String getCatname() {
        return catname;
    }

    public void setTopicName(String topicName) {
        this.topicName = topicName;
    }
    public String getTopicName() {
        return topicName;
    }

    public void setChild(ArrayList<SMByTopicCategory> child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public String getMainTopicJson() {
        return MainTopicJson;
    }

    public void setMainTopicJson(String mainTopicJson) {
        MainTopicJson = mainTopicJson;
    }

    public ArrayList<SMByTopicCategory> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setQuestions(ArrayList<SMByTopicSubCategory> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public ArrayList<SMByTopicSubCategory> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public ArrayList<MByTopics> getByTopicList() {
        ArrayList<MByTopics> mByTopicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<11;i++){
            MByTopics mQuestionBankCategory=new MByTopics();

            if (i==1 || i== 5|| i==9){
                mQuestionBankCategory.setTopicName("Microeconomics");
            }else  if (i==2 || i== 10|| i==6) {
                mQuestionBankCategory.setTopicName("Macroeconomics");
            }else {
                mQuestionBankCategory.setTopicName("Current Isssues");
            }

            mByTopicsArrayList.add(mQuestionBankCategory);
        }

        return mByTopicsArrayList;
    }

}
```

Comment: explanations would be nice

Comment: Codes are not clean, and no explanations!

Answer (score 3):

#### Now you need [1 adapter](https://github.com/khemrajsharma/RecyclerBindingExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ks/nestedrecyclerbindingexample/adapters/GeneralAdapter.java) for all `RecyclerView`

- One adapter can be used in for all RecyclerView. So **NO** `onBindViewHolder`, **No** `onCreateViewHolder` handling.
- No code for setting adapter from Java/Kotlin class. Check [sample class](https://github.com/khemrajsharma/RecyclerBindingExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ks/nestedrecyclerbindingexample/MainActivity.java).
- You can set events and custom data for every list by using [Binding Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

[image: screenshot]

I show here setting two different `RecyclerView` by 1 adapter -

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="listOne"
            type="java.util.List"/>

        <variable
            name="listTwo"
            type="java.util.List"/>

        <variable
            name="onItemClickListenerOne"
            type="com.ks.nestedrecyclerbindingexample.callbacks.OnItemClickListener"/>

        <variable
            name="onItemClickListenerTwo"
            type="com.ks.nestedrecyclerbindingexample.callbacks.OnItemClickListener"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            rvItemLayout="@{@layout/row_one}"
            rvList="@{listOne}"
            rvOnItemClick="@{onItemClickListenerOne}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            rvItemLayout="@{@layout/row_two}"
            rvList="@{listTwo}"
            rvOnItemClick="@{onItemClickListenerTwo}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

You can see I pass list, item layout id and click listener from layout.

```
rvItemLayout="@{@layout/row_one}"
rvList="@{listOne}"
rvOnItemClick="@{onItemClickListenerOne}"
```

This custom attributes are created by **[BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)**.

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter(value = {"rvItemLayout", "rvList", "rvOnItemClick"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void setRvAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, int rvItemLayout, List rvList, @Nullable OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        if (rvItemLayout != 0 && rvList != null && rvList.size() > 0)
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new GeneralAdapter(rvItemLayout, rvList, onItemClickListener));
    }
}
```

Now from Activity, you pass list, click listener like

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityHomeBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home);
        binding.setListOne(new ArrayList()); // pass your list or set list from response of API
        binding.setListTwo(new ArrayList());
        binding.setOnItemClickListenerOne(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, Object object) {
                if (object instanceof ModelParent) {
                    // TODO: your action here
                }
            }
        });
        binding.setOnItemClickListenerTwo(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, Object object) {
                if (object instanceof ModelChild) {
                    // TODO: your action here  
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### You don't want read too much, directly clone/download **[full example](https://github.com/khemrajsharma/RecyclerBindingExample)** on from my github repo. And try it yourself.

You can see `GeneralAdapter.java` in above repo.

If you have problems while setting up data binding, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563).

Answer (score 2):

Since I cant comment yet im gonna post as an answer the link.. I have found a simple, well organized tutorial on recyclerview
http://www.androiddeft.com/2017/10/01/recyclerview-android/

Apart from that when you are going to add a recycler view into you activity what you want to do is as below and how you should do this has been described on the link

- add RecyclerView component into your layout file
- make a class which you are going to display as list rows
- make a layout file which is the layout of a row of you list
- now we need a custom adapter so create a custom adapter by extending
  from the parent class RecyclerView.Adapter
- add recyclerview into your mainActivity oncreate
- adding separators
- adding Touch listeners

Answer (score 2):

You can use abstract adapter with diff utils and filter

**SimpleAbstractAdapter.kt**

```
abstract class SimpleAbstractAdapter<T>(private var items: ArrayList<T> = arrayListOf()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAbstractAdapter.VH>() {
   protected var listener: OnViewHolderListener<T>? = null
   private val filter = ArrayFilter()
   private val lock = Any()
   protected abstract fun getLayout(): Int
   protected abstract fun bindView(item: T, viewHolder: VH)
   protected abstract fun getDiffCallback(): DiffCallback<T>?
   private var onFilterObjectCallback: OnFilterObjectCallback? = null
   private var constraint: CharSequence? = ""

override fun onBindViewHolder(vh: VH, position: Int) {
    getItem(position)?.let { bindView(it, vh) }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
    return VH(parent, getLayout())
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

protected abstract class DiffCallback<T> : DiffUtil.Callback() {
    private val mOldItems = ArrayList<T>()
    private val mNewItems = ArrayList<T>()

    fun setItems(oldItems: List<T>, newItems: List<T>) {
        mOldItems.clear()
        mOldItems.addAll(oldItems)
        mNewItems.clear()
        mNewItems.addAll(newItems)
    }

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return mOldItems.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return mNewItems.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return areItemsTheSame(
                mOldItems[oldItemPosition],
                mNewItems[newItemPosition]
        )
    }

    abstract fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return areContentsTheSame(
                mOldItems[oldItemPosition],
                mNewItems[newItemPosition]
        )
    }

    abstract fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean
}

class VH(parent: ViewGroup, @LayoutRes layout: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout, parent, false))

interface OnViewHolderListener<T> {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int, item: T)
}

fun getItem(position: Int): T? {
    return items.getOrNull(position)
}

fun getItems(): ArrayList<T> {
    return items
}

fun setViewHolderListener(listener: OnViewHolderListener<T>) {
    this.listener = listener
}

fun addAll(list: List<T>) {
    val diffCallback = getDiffCallback()
    when {
        diffCallback != null && !items.isEmpty() -> {
            diffCallback.setItems(items, list)
            val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
            items.clear()
            items.addAll(list)
            diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        }
        diffCallback == null && !items.isEmpty() -> {
            items.clear()
            items.addAll(list)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        else -> {
            items.addAll(list)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}

fun add(item: T) {
    items.add(item)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun add(position:Int, item: T) {
    items.add(position,item)
    notifyItemInserted(position)
}

fun remove(position: Int) {
    items.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

fun remove(item: T) {
    items.remove(item)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun clear(notify: Boolean=false) {
    items.clear()
    if (notify) {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

fun setFilter(filter: SimpleAdapterFilter<T>): ArrayFilter {
    return this.filter.setFilter(filter)
}

interface SimpleAdapterFilter<T> {
    fun onFilterItem(contains: CharSequence, item: T): Boolean
}

fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any): CharSequence {
    return filter.convertResultToString(resultValue)
}

fun filter(constraint: CharSequence) {
    this.constraint = constraint
    filter.filter(constraint)
}

fun filter(constraint: CharSequence, listener: Filter.FilterListener) {
    this.constraint = constraint
    filter.filter(constraint, listener)
}

fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return filter
}

interface OnFilterObjectCallback {
    fun handle(countFilterObject: Int)
}

fun setOnFilterObjectCallback(objectCallback: OnFilterObjectCallback) {
    onFilterObjectCallback = objectCallback
}

inner class ArrayFilter : Filter() {
    private var original: ArrayList<T> = arrayListOf()
    private var filter: SimpleAdapterFilter<T> = DefaultFilter()
    private var list: ArrayList<T> = arrayListOf()
    private var values: ArrayList<T> = arrayListOf()


    fun setFilter(filter: SimpleAdapterFilter<T>): ArrayFilter {
        original = items
        this.filter = filter
        return this
    }

    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
        val results = Filter.FilterResults()
        if (constraint == null || constraint.isBlank()) {
            synchronized(lock) {
                list = original
            }
            results.values = list
            results.count = list.size
        } else {
            synchronized(lock) {
                values = original
            }
            val result = ArrayList<T>()
            for (value in values) {
                if (constraint!=null && constraint.trim().isNotEmpty() && value != null) {
                    if (filter.onFilterItem(constraint, value)) {
                        result.add(value)
                    }
                } else {
                    value?.let { result.add(it) }
                }
            }
            results.values = result
            results.count = result.size
        }
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: Filter.FilterResults) {
        items = results.values as? ArrayList<T> ?: arrayListOf()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        onFilterObjectCallback?.handle(results.count)
    }

}

class DefaultFilter<T> : SimpleAdapterFilter<T> {
    override fun onFilterItem(contains: CharSequence, item: T): Boolean {
        val valueText = item.toString().toLowerCase()
        if (valueText.startsWith(contains.toString())) {
            return true
        } else {
            val words = valueText.split(" ".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            for (word in words) {
                if (word.contains(contains)) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
  }
}
```

And extend abstract adapter with implements methods

**TasksAdapter.kt**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.task_item_layout.view.*

class TasksAdapter(private val listener:TasksListener? = null) : SimpleAbstractAdapter<Task>() {
override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.task_item_layout
}

override fun getDiffCallback(): DiffCallback<Task>? {
    return object : DiffCallback<Task>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.items == newItem.items
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun bindView(item: Task, viewHolder: VH) {
    viewHolder.itemView.apply {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        val customer = item.customer
        val customerName = if (customer != null) customer.name else ""
        tvTaskCommentTitle.text = customerName + ", #" + item.id
        tvCommentContent.text = item.taskAddress
        ivCall.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onCallClick(position, item)
        }
        setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onItemClick(position, item)
        }
    }
}

 interface TasksListener : SimpleAbstractAdapter.OnViewHolderListener<Task> {
    fun onCallClick(position: Int, item: Task)
 }
}
```

Init adapter

```
mAdapter = TasksAdapter(object : TasksAdapter.TasksListener {
            override fun onCallClick(position: Int, item:Task) {
            }

            override fun onItemClick(position: Int, item:Task) {

            }
        })
rvTasks.adapter = mAdapter
```

and fill

```
mAdapter?.addAll(tasks)
```

add custom filter

```
mAdapter?.setFilter(object : SimpleAbstractAdapter.SimpleAdapterFilter<MoveTask> {
            override fun onFilterItem(contains: CharSequence, item:Task): Boolean {
                return contains.toString().toLowerCase().contains(item.id?.toLowerCase().toString())
            }
    })
```

filter data

```
mAdapter?.filter("test")
```

Comment: add some changes with diff utils,add type support
https://gist.github.com/arnyigor/568035c6db9bdbeaf609b68a71834349

Answer (score 1):

implementation androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:....
It is advised to update to the androidx libraries which are here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

The layout file Widget XML tag then must be updated to:
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: You're right. I need to update my answer with AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds it insane that most of these "minimal" examples involve creating at least 4 different files just to create a simple tool.

Here is a stand-alone activity in Kotlin (built upon [this answer from Saifur Rahman Mohsin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143512/851699)) that implements a basic recycler view:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ModelDownloaderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val items = (1..50).toList().map { "Item #$it" }
    inner class ItemHolder(view: View, var textField: TextView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Create recycler view, or find it in Activity's XML file if you prefer
        val myLayoutResource: Int? = null // Replace with R.layout.activity_model_downloader if you want to use an XML layout with a recycler view in it
        val recyclerView = myLayoutResource?.let {
            setContentView(it)
            findViewById(R.id.modelRecyclerView) // Replace with ID of your recycler view in layout
        } ?: RecyclerView(this).also { setContentView(ConstraintLayout(this).apply { addView(it) }) }

        // Bind controls to it.
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder>() {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
                ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false))
            override fun getItemCount() = items.size
            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
                holder.textField.text = items[position]
                holder.textField.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ModelDownloaderActivity, "Clicked $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```