# Error Using Recycle View on android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a app with 3 screens, first one I insert contacts info like name, address, e-mail, cellphone... Second screen I put social network links,
and thir one I show all contacts info in a RecyclerView but when I click on the button to go to third screen I'm getting stuck on this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.person.bernardo.myperson, PID: 14891
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.person.bernardo.myperson/com.person.bernardo.myperson.RecyclerViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.person.bernardo.myperson.RecyclerViewActivity cannot be cast to com.person.bernardo.myperson.PessoaAdapter$ItemClickListener
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2785)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.person.bernardo.myperson.RecyclerViewActivity cannot be cast to com.person.bernardo.myperson.PessoaAdapter$ItemClickListener
                  at com.person.bernardo.myperson.RecyclerViewActivity.onCreate(RecyclerViewActivity.java:47)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6847)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2785) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

My Code:

```
    /**
 * ---------------------------------------------- Documentacao preliminar
 * Pontificia Universidade Catolica de Minas Gerais
 * Curso de Ciencia da Computacao
 * LDDM
 * <p>
 * Autor: Bernardo Morais Alfredo  Matricula: 565524
 * Versao:  0.06                Data: 18/03/2018
 * <p>
 * Dados:
 * - Ler dados de uma pessoa e criar evento no calendario.
 * <p>
 * Para funcionar:
 * <p>
 * Insira (nas dependencies de build.gradle (Module:App) :
 * compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 * compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
 * compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
 * <p>
 * Resultados:
 * <p>
 * -Funciona
 * <p>
 * Feito com ajuda de:
 * Luiz Braganca
 */
package com.person.bernardo.myperson;

import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Pessoa contato = new Pessoa();
    EditText nome, nasc, tel, email, endereco;
    // Variavel para utilizar o vibrador
    private Vibrator vib;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBotoes();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo para converter EditText em String.
     * @param txt
     * @return
     */
    public String converteTexto(EditText txt) {
        // definir dados
        String resp = txt.getText().toString();
        return (resp);
    }// end converteTexto( )

    /**
     * Metodo para verificar cada botao.
     */
    private void setBotoes() {
        // definindo botoes
        Button addContato = findViewById(R.id.addContato),
                salvaAniv = findViewById(R.id.anivesario),
                envWhatsapp = findViewById(R.id.whatsapp),
                save = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nome = findViewById(R.id.nome);
                nasc = findViewById(R.id.nascimento);
                tel = findViewById(R.id.phone);
                email = findViewById(R.id.email);
                endereco = findViewById(R.id.endereco);
            }// end onClick( )
        });

        // definindo os editText
        nome = findViewById(R.id.nome);
        nasc = findViewById(R.id.nascimento);
        tel = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
                endereco = findViewById(R.id.endereco);

        final TextInputLayout nomeInput = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_nome),
                nascInput = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_data),
                telInput = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_telefone),
                emailInput = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email),
                endInput = findViewById(R.id.input_layout_endereco);

        //Inicializando a variavel vibrator
        vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // botao de adicionar contato
        addContato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean emptyNome = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(nome)),
                        emptyEmail = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(email)),
                        emptytel = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(tel)),
                        emptyAddress = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(endereco));

                //Mostrar Erro se Nome Vazio
                if (emptyNome) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    nomeInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    nomeInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Nome));
                }// end if

                //Mostrar Erro se Email Vazio
                if (emptyEmail) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    emailInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    emailInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Email));
                }// end if

                //Mostrar Erro se Telefone Vazio
                if (emptytel) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    telInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    telInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Tel));
                }// end if

                //Mostrar Erro se Address Vazio
                if (emptyAddress) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    endInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    endInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Endereco));
                }// end if

                //Se os campos nao estiverem vazios:
                if (!emptyNome && !emptyEmail && !emptytel && !emptyAddress) {
                    nomeInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    emailInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    telInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    endInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    contato.setNome(converteTexto(nome));
                    contato.setEmail((converteTexto(email)));
                    contato.setTelefone((converteTexto(tel)));
                    contato.setEndereco((converteTexto(endereco)));
                    addContact(converteTexto(nome), converteTexto(email), converteTexto(tel), converteTexto(endereco));
                }// end if
            }// end onClick( )
        });

        // botao de salvar aniversario
        salvaAniv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean emptyNome = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(nome)),
                        emptyData = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(nasc));

                //Mostrar erro se nome vazio.
                if (emptyNome) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    nomeInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    nomeInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Nome));
                }// end if

                //Mostrar erro se data de nascimento vazia.
                if (emptyData) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    nascInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    nascInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Nasc));
                }// end if

                if (!emptyNome && !emptyData) {
                    nomeInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    nascInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    aniversario(converteTexto(nome), converteTexto(nasc));
                }// end if
            }// end onClick
        });

        // botao de enviar whatsapp
        envWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean emptyTel = TextUtils.isEmpty(converteTexto(tel));

                //Mostrar erro se telefone vazio.
                if (emptyTel) {
                    vib.vibrate(120);
                    telInput.setErrorEnabled(true);
                    telInput.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_EditText_Tel));
                }// end if

                //Mostrar erro.
                if (!emptyTel) {
                    telInput.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    whatsapp(converteTexto(tel));
                }// end if
            }// end onClick
        });
    }// end setBotoes( )

    /**
     * Metodo addContact( ) - adicionar um contato.
     *
     * @Param: -Nome = nome contato
     * -Email = email contato
     * -Tel = Telefone contato
     * -End = endereco contato
     */
    public void addContact(String nome, String email, String tel, String end) {
        //define o contato

        // set intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

        // set nome
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, nome);

        // set email
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME);

        // set telefone
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, tel);
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME);

        // set endereco
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, end);
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME);

        // set intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }// end addContact( )

    /**
     * Metodo para adicionar data de aniversário na agenda.
     */
    public void aniversario(String nome, String nasc) {

        // set data
        int dia, mes, year;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);

        contato.setAniversario(nasc);

        // get day
        dia = Pessoa.getDia(nasc);
        contato.setDia(dia);

        // get month
        mes = Pessoa.getMes(nasc);
        contato.setMes(mes);

        // get year
        year = Pessoa.getYear(nasc);
        contato.setAno(year);

        // set date
        intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);

        // set event title
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Aniversário de " + nome);

        // set event time
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

        // set start day
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(2018, mes, dia, 0, 0);

        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, startTime.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");

        // iniciando a activity
        startActivity(intent);
    }// end aniversario( )

    /**
     * Metodo que manda mensagem pelo whatsapp.
     *
     * @Param: -Numero Telefone
     */
    public void whatsapp(String number) {
        contato.setTelefone(number);

        // send contact number
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);

        // start intent
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);

        // text type
        sendIntent.setPackage("text/plain");

        // add whatsapp package
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        // start activity
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
    }// end whatsapp( )

    /**
     * Metodo que vai para a segunda tela.
     * @param view
     */
    public void segundaTela(View view) {
        // criando a intent para a segunda tela
        Intent secondScreen = new Intent(this, MainSocial.class);
        Pessoa proxPessoa = new Pessoa();

        proxPessoa.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
        proxPessoa.setTelefone(tel.getText().toString());
        proxPessoa.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        proxPessoa.setEndereco(endereco.getText().toString());
        proxPessoa.setAniversario(nasc.getText().toString());

        secondScreen.putExtra("proxPessoa", proxPessoa);

        // iniciando
        startActivity(secondScreen);
    }// end segundaTela( )

}// end class


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainSocial extends AppCompatActivity {

    Pessoa receivePessoa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_social);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        receivePessoa = (Pessoa) intent.getSerializableExtra("proxPessoa");

        pegarDados();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo para converter EditText em String.
     *
     * @param txt
     * @return
     */
    public String editTextToString(EditText txt) {
        // definir dados
        String resp = "";
        if (txt != null) {
            resp = txt.getText().toString();
        } else {
            resp = "";
        }
        return (resp);
    }// end converteTexto( )


    /**
     * Metodo para salvar os dados de cada rede no contato, se null = "".
     *
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    public void pegarDados() {

        Button save = findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText facebook = findViewById(R.id.facebook);
                String face = editTextToString(facebook);
                receivePessoa.setFacebook(face);

                EditText instagram = findViewById(R.id.instagram);
                String insta = editTextToString(instagram);
                receivePessoa.setInstagram(insta);

                EditText linkedin = findViewById(R.id.linkedin);
                String link = editTextToString(linkedin);
                receivePessoa.setLinkedIn(link);

                EditText spotify = findViewById(R.id.spotify);
                String spot = editTextToString(spotify);
                receivePessoa.setSpotify(spot);

                EditText twitter = findViewById(R.id.twitter);
                String twit = editTextToString(twitter);
                receivePessoa.setTwitter(twit);

                EditText youtube = findViewById(R.id.youtube);
                String yout = editTextToString(youtube);
                receivePessoa.setYoutube(yout);
            }// end onClick( )
        });
    }

    /**
     * Metodo que vai para a segunda tela.
     *
     * @param view
     */
    public void terceiraTela(View view) {
        // criando a intent para a terceira tela com RecycleView
        Intent terceiraTela = new Intent(this, RecyclerViewActivity.class);
        terceiraTela.putExtra("pessoa2", receivePessoa);

        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getNome());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getTelefone());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getEmail());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getEndereco());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getFacebook());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getInstagram());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getLinkedIn());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getTwitter());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getSpotify());
        System.out.println(receivePessoa.getYoutube());


        // iniciando
        startActivity(terceiraTela);
    }// end terceiraTela( )

}

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PessoaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PessoaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    PessoaAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_nome);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

    public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PessoaAdapter adapter;
    Pessoa contato;
    private List<Pessoa> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view_activity);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        contato = (Pessoa) intent.getSerializableExtra("pessoa2");

        ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
        animalNames.add(contato.getNome());
        animalNames.add(contato.getTelefone());
        animalNames.add(contato.getEmail());
        animalNames.add(contato.getEndereco());
        animalNames.add(contato.getFacebook());
        animalNames.add(contato.getLinkedIn());
        animalNames.add(contato.getInstagram());
        animalNames.add(contato.getYoutube());
        animalNames.add(contato.getSpotify());

        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new PessoaAdapter(this, animalNames);
        adapter.setClickListener((PessoaAdapter.ItemClickListener) this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I tried using this sample [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)

[GitHub Link For Complete Code](https://github.com/gatesco/MyPerson)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move out the `interface` out of the `PessoaAdapter` class.

Create a new class `ItemClickListener.java` like the following.

```
package com.person.bernardo.myperson;

import android.view.View;

public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Now in your `RecyclerViewActivity` implement the `ItemClickListener` like the following and while setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView`, you set the listener along with the adapter.

```
package com.person.bernardo.myperson;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClickListener {

    PessoaAdapter adapter;
    Pessoa contato;
    private List<Pessoa> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        contato = (Pessoa) intent.getSerializableExtra("pessoa2");

        ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
        animalNames.add(contato.getNome());
        animalNames.add(contato.getTelefone());
        animalNames.add(contato.getEmail());
        animalNames.add(contato.getEndereco());
        animalNames.add(contato.getFacebook());
        animalNames.add(contato.getLinkedIn());
        animalNames.add(contato.getInstagram());
        animalNames.add(contato.getYoutube());
        animalNames.add(contato.getSpotify());

        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        // Error in the following line
        adapter = new PessoaAdapter(this, animalNames);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // Do something based on the item click in the RecyclerView
    }
}
```

And the modified adapter will look like the following.

```
package com.person.bernardo.myperson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class PessoaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PessoaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    PessoaAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_nome);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null)
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

I have downloaded your code from github and modified the code in a branch of mine which is locally created. Please check the pull request in the fix branch in your [github repository](https://github.com/gatesco/MyPerson/pulls).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great to know that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line

```
adapter.setClickListener((PessoaAdapter.ItemClickListener) this);
```

You should do like this

1. Let class `RecyclerViewActivity` implement interface `PessoaAdapter.ItemClickListener`

`public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PessoaAdapter.ItemClickListener{`

2. Add method to class `RecyclerViewActivity`

   `void onItemClick(View view, int position){ your code }`
3. You don't need to cast anymore

`adapter.setClickListener(this);`

Read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html