# how to connect a Listview with a database?

Tags: java, android

i have database i maked it with DB Browser for SQLite

Link DataBase [ [HERE](https://ufile.io/tbzfr) ]

i puted the DB inside folder Assest ok ?

now how can i make Layout have ListView and read from the DB

when i press item from Listview my app will be read from DB and show it in

new Layout : Like This Example

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a simple `ListView` when querying data, you should deffinetely Check out `RecyclerViews` and `ViewHolder` pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example

Comment: duplicate of . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application

Comment: anyhelp guys!!!

Answer (score -1):

You should create your `CursorAdapter` to do such things i can reccomed you this tutorial:
[sql tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)