# Android - How to fit each TableRow to the screen height

Tags: android

I'm looking to create a table with 3 cells (TableRow) each cell should have the dimensions of the size of the full screen (width and height).

Should I use something other than a TableLayout to get the same effect?

Thanks a lot.

[Here is an example of the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oauBE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing this will be by using a **`RecyclerView`** along with a Vertical Layout Manager, each and every one of your element will have width and height as match parent.

Comment: Thank you very much! it is working great! here is an example of how to use RecyclerView with a Vertical Layout Manager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example

Comment: glad I could help @gal.m