# How do I show a DialogFragment from an OnClick on a RecyclerView?

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have a `Fragment` (`FragmentColourSets`) which shows a `RecyclerView`.  I want to be able to click on an item in the `RecyclerView`, and to then see a `DialogFragment` showing information on that item. I expected there to be an `OnClickListener` in the `RecyclerView` which would handle this, but I now see that there isn't, and I'm stuck.  Solutions I've found have involved adding a click listener in the Adapter, but from there I can't access the `FragmentManager` or `Context` in order to show the `DialogFragment`.

So, the relevant part of the `FragmentColourSets` layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_colour_sets"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `FragmentColourSets` class is (I've left out some irrelevant stuff to keep it shorter):

```
public class FragmentColourSets extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<ColourSet> mColourSets;
    private Context             mContext;
    private FirebaseFirestore   mDb;
    private RecyclerView        mRVColourSets;
    private String              mUid;

    private FragmentManager     mFragmentManager;

    static public FragmentCurrentColourSets newInstance(Context context, ArrayList<ColourSet> colourSets) {

        FragmentCurrentColourSets f = new FragmentColourSets();
        f.setRequiredData(context, colourSets);

        return f;
    }

    public void setRequiredData(Context context, ArrayList<ColourSet> colourSets) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mCurrentColourSets = colourSets;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colour_sets, container, false);

        mRVColourSets = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_colour_sets);

        mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        // Set up Layout Manager, and set Recycler View to use it
        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRVColourSets.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getActivity();

    }

    // Set colour sets to be shown
    public void setColourSets(ArrayList<ColourSet> coloursets) {
        mColourSets = coloursets;
        fillView();
    }

    public void setUid(String thisUid) { mUid = thisUid; }

    public void setDb(FirebaseFirestore db) { mDb = db; }

    /**
     * fillView
     * List current Colour Sets in recycler view
     * This takes the colour sets and shows them
     **/
    private void fillView() {

        if(mRVColourSets == null)   return;
        if(mColourSets == null) return;

        AdapterListColourSets mAdapter = new AdapterListColourSets(mColourSets);

        mRVColourSets.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

`AdapterListColourSets` is:

```
public class AdapterListColourSets extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListColourSets.ViewHolderColourSet> {

        private ArrayList<ColourSet>    colourSets;

        public AdapterListColourSets(ArrayList<ColourSet> colourSets) {
            this.colourSets=colourSets;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolderColourSet onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View layoutColourSets = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_colour_set, null);
            return new ViewHolderColourSet(layoutColourSets);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderColourSet holder, int position) {
            holder.colourSetName.setText(colourSets.get(position).getName());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return colourSets.size();
        }

        class ViewHolderColourSet extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView colourSetName, colourSetKey;

            ViewHolderColourSet(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                colourSetName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_colour_set_name);
                colourSetKey = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_colour_set_key);

            }
        }
    }
```

So, at some point I need to attach an OnClick listener to each item shown in the `RecyclerView`, so that I can do something like this:

```
private void onClick() {

    DFEditColourSet dfEdit 
           = DFEditColourSet.newInstance(mContext);
    dfEdit.show(mFragmentManager, "Edit Colour Set");
}
```

However, within the adapter I don't have access to the `Context` or to the `FragmentManager`. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of resources out there that show you how this can be done.
Take a look at this [blog post](https://www.andreasjakl.com/recyclerview-kotlin-style-click-listener-android/).
Regarding your question of the context not being available in your adapter: just pass it in as a constructor argument. <s>This can be seen in [this example repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample).</s>

Sharing the data between the two fragments could be done using a [`SharedViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

If you can't figure it out, feel free to ask more questions.

**EDIT**
I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425/6409815) to a similar question, which might offer a solution that is more easy to implement than the blog post I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't manage to find a few examples online myself; they just didn't show up when I searched! Also don't know why I didn't think to pass the context in... this is why I shouldn't code when I'm tired!