# Clickable image not responding with a RecyclerView.setOnClickListener() in a Fragment... Why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, clickable

I've set up a recyclerView which contains 4 images inside a fragment. I want a toast to appear after clicking the image. I've set up the recyclerAdapter successfully and implemented a listener in the main activity. Should I be trying to set up a clickable image from the recyclerAdapter and not recyclerView? Thanks for any help!

```
public class topFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int[] images = {R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2, R.drawable.3, R.drawable.4};
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private OnImageListener onImageListener;

    public interface OnImageListener{
        public void onImageListener(int[] i);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(images);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder= new RecyclerAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view.findViewById(R.id.album));
                for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++){
                    RecyclerAdapter rA = new RecyclerAdapter(images);
                    if (rA.equals(0)){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (rA.equals(1)){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "2!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (rA.equals(2)){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "3!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (rA.equals(3)){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "4!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    onImageListener.onImageListener(images);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Activity activity = (Activity)context;
        try{
            onImageListener = (OnImageListener)activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+"must implement onImage...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Should I be trying to set up a clickable image from the recyclerAdapter and not recyclerView?" – Basically, yes. `RecyclerView` will not fire an `OnClickListener`. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40584424) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll have to set the imageview's listener from your adapter...something similar to the snippet below...

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnImageClickedListener listener;

    public void setListener(OnImageClickedListener listener){
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;

        private ViewHolder(View root) {

            super(root);

            imageView = root.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) listener.onImageClicked(v.getTag());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnImageClickedListener {
        void onImageClicked(Object tag);
    }
}
```

And you would use it as below...

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter();
adapter.setListener(new YourAdapter.OnImageClickedListener{

   public void onImageClicked(){
       //TODO: display that toast
   }
});
```