# App crash when trying to move intent to another adapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I have two Adapter class for RecyclerView. I want the ImageView inside one Adapter class to display the other Adapter class

I already tried to use intent on MainActivity

```
// listener for image
        cardViewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnItemClick(
                i, new CustomOnItemClick.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
            Intent detail = new Intent(context,DetailAdapter.class);
                context.startActivity(detail);
            }
        }
        ));
```

here is the link for what the application supposed to be
**https://ibb.co/gmnnghw**
 **https://giphy.com/gifs/Y3NK0lHfAcN1dGbCZX**

> CardViewDeviceAdapter

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardViewDeviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDeviceAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Device> deviceArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Device> getDeviceArrayList() {
        return deviceArrayList;
    }



    public void setDeviceArrayList(ArrayList<Device> deviceArrayList) {
        this.deviceArrayList = deviceArrayList;
    }

    public CardViewDeviceAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_device, viewGroup, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int i) {
        Device d = getDeviceArrayList().get(i);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(d.getPhoto())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(350, 550))
                .into(cardViewHolder.photo);

        cardViewHolder.title.setText(d.getTitle());
        cardViewHolder.detail.setText(d.getDetail());


        // listener untuk button favorite
        cardViewHolder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnItemClick(
                i, new CustomOnItemClick.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Favorite device"+getDeviceArrayList()
                .get(position)
                .getTitle()
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        ));

        // listener untuk button share
        cardViewHolder.share.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnItemClick(
                i, new CustomOnItemClick.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Share device"+getDeviceArrayList()
                                .get(position)
                                .getTitle()
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        ));

        // listener untuk image
        cardViewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnItemClick(
                i, new CustomOnItemClick.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                Intent detail = new Intent(context, DetailAdapter.class);
                context.startActivity(detail);
            }
        }
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getDeviceArrayList().size();
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView photo;
        TextView title, detail;
        Button favorite, share;
        public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_photo);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_name);
            detail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_details);
            favorite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_favourite);
            share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_share);
        }
    }
}
```

> DetailAdapter

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailAdapter.DetailHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Device> deviceArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Device> getDeviceArrayList() {
        return deviceArrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DetailAdapter.DetailHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail_adapter, viewGroup, false);
        return new DetailAdapter.DetailHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DetailAdapter.DetailHolder detailHolder, int i) {
        Device d = getDeviceArrayList().get(i);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(d.getPhoto())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(350, 550))
                .into(detailHolder.photo);

        detailHolder.title.setText(d.getTitle());
        detailHolder.detail.setText(d.getDetail());
        detailHolder.summary.setText(d.getSummary());
        detailHolder.origin.setText(d.getOrigin());
        detailHolder.market_value.setText(d.getMarket_value());
        detailHolder.consumer.setText(d.getConsumer());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getDeviceArrayList().size();
    }


    public class DetailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView photo;
        TextView title, detail, summary, origin, market_value, consumer;
        public DetailHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            photo = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_detail);
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.title_title);
            detail = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
            summary = view.findViewById(R.id.detail_detail);
            origin = view.findViewById(R.id.origin_year);
            market_value = view.findViewById(R.id.market_value);
            consumer = view.findViewById(R.id.konsumer);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it asks for explicit activity on `AndroidManifest.xml` ,
but I can't assign `DetailAdapter` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

***Logcat***

```
2019-05-29 17:38:59.097 8897-8897/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8897
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.DetailAdapter}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2012)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1675)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at com.example.myapplication.CardViewDeviceAdapter$3.onItemClicked(CardViewDeviceAdapter.java:89)
        at com.example.myapplication.CustomOnItemClick.onClick(CustomOnItemClick.java:16)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:782)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25945)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

App crashses when tapping on Image

Comment: `DetailAdapter` is your adapter?

Comment: Any of variable will be _null_. `context`or `adapter` anything.

Comment: post your log...

Comment: Please provide your full code, for understanding your problem. And startActivty() method used to start an Activity, not an Adapter.

Comment: Yes, `DetailAdapter` is my adapter

Comment: you can navigate to activity only so `DetailAdapter` should be Actvity and it's mentioned in Manifest

Comment: how to make `DetailAdapter` an activity?

Comment: @RajasekaranM How should you do that?

Comment: you have to create separate activity  and design your list there.

Comment: post your manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got all the concept of RecyclerView wrong. Check out how to use RecyclerView from 
[Simple RecyclerView Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)

What you're trying to do is launch `RecyclerView` like an Activity. Your `RecyclerView` is **not an activity**, it is a **view**.
In the gif you've attached to shown what you want to accomplish, it's a completely different thing. After clicking the item in RecyclerView, a new activity is launched with SharedElement transition. Your `DetailAdapter` should be `AppCompatActivity`.

To correct your error, make your `DetailAdapter` extend `AppCompatActivity`, after doing that, while launching the `DetailAdapter` with Intent, [pass the data like title, detail through Intent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: How do you pass data to certain array?

Comment: I didn't get your question.