# How to define ViewHolder's constructor when I defining recyclerView with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to define a `recyclerView` with kotlin for first time. But I have a problem in viewHodler's constructor.

I don't know how to define ViewHolder's Constructor. Do I have to define a secondary constructor?

My code is:

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    var array = ArrayList<Note>()
    // onCreateView 
    // getItemCount
    //onBindViewHolder
}

class ViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder{}// my view has a textView that i want to initialise but i don't know where do it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example by google: [custom adapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView/blob/master/kotlinApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerview/CustomAdapter.kt)

Example in stackoverflow: [simple recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)

**Here is a simple usage with `textView` (from the official android developers website):**

```
class MyViewHolder(val textView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
    // create a new view
    val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false) as TextView
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    return MyViewHolder(textView)
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
}
```

I highly suggest you to go through [recyclerView-android-devs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and [understanding-recyclerview-medium](https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/understanding-recyclerview-part-1-the-basics-a7bd07cfae93).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example `NotesViewHolder` in Kotlin:

```
class NotesViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(note: Note) {
        // Bind your note stuff here
    }
}

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesViewHolder>() {
    var array = ArrayList<Note>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        // TODO: Create you ViewHolder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        // TODO: Set item count here
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(array[position])
    }
}
```