# Dynamic creation of view (textView, imageVIew etc.) in loop hangs the Android device. How to solve this?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, profiler, android-profiler

I am creating **dynamic views** and adding it to the parent layout in a loop. So, when the data is much bigger, then it **hangs the android system** while setting the view.

How to stop this ? Or any better way to populate large dynamic data which does not hangs up the device.

**Basic operation :**

1. I get a list of data with some format information
2. Run a loop and create views dynamically based on the switch case for different type of data (text, image, link, etc.) and add that view to the parent layout.

Comment: Please use RecyclerView with multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use to dynamic adding a lot of UI elements to screen by hand without using RecyclerView. There are two ways how to propagate your data to screen with RecyclerView.

1. For each data type create UI component with header like `class CurrentItem(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), DataTypeItem`. *DataTypeItem* is interface for each data type. Than create `RecyclerView` and to in the adapter `RecyclerView.Adapter<DataTypeItem>`. Now your adapter is able to show all your data types with interface `DataTypeItem`. In adapter override method `onBindViewHolder(holder: DataTypeItem, position: Int)` and re-type holder to `CurrentItem`. On the end propagate your incoming data to UI component.
2. Create layouts for your data only without UI components. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example?answertab=votes#tab-top) is a nice example, how to do it.

Comment: On use recyclerView to populate the dynamic views, onScroll of the recyclerView, the data item order changes. How to prevent that from happening ? @dzejkob23

Comment: If your incoming data order has changed then you can create a map with indexes. These indexes are items positions on the screen in adapter. If you change all items call `notifyDataSetChanged`, only items range `notifyItemRangeChanged`, only one item `notifyItemChanged` or `notifyItemMoved`. By these methods you are able to propagate changes the screen.