# ClassCastException when casting View.getContext() to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception, androidx, fragmentmanager

When I attempt to start a Fragment from an Adapter, I get this exception.

I looked for similar issues, but casting to androidX is relatively new, so I couldn't find relevant solutions.
I found a solution for passing a FragmentManager to the constructor when creating an Adapter object. This also required initilalizing a FragmentMAnager, and that's where I got stuck again.

The code for the process is:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
    int id = currentCountry.getId();

    Fragment mdf = new DetailsFragment();

    activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragments_container, mdf)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

The exception message is

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.`

Any ideas for a solution? maybe the last option will be reverting back to android from androidX.

Is there other code that's needed to figure this issue out?

Comment: @d-joe is v view in adapter? how do you inflate it? It seems that you inflate your view using application context, it can lead you to problems, because theme associates with activity context.

Comment: You shouldn't be performing a `FragmentTransaction` in an `Adapter`. Instead, create an `interface` to relay the click (or whatever action) back to the `Activity`, and let it do the transaction. If you really don't want to do that, for some reason, then just modify your `Adapter` to take an `AppCompatActivity` specifically in its constructor, and use that, rather than trying to cast a `View`'s `Context`.

Comment: @MikeM. you mean doing the transaction in an Interface?

Comment: I don't know what that `Adapter` is for, but I mean like the `ItemClickListener` interface demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425). Note how the `Activity` implements the interface, and a `Toast` is shown in `onItemClick()`. Instead of the `Toast`, you would do your transaction.

Comment: I tried implementing the Interface and methods as demonstrated in the link you added. I think it works. I also need to get the clicked position back to the ListActivity from which the list Adapter is instantiated, or, better, get the clicked item data through the Adapter method getAdapterPosition().

Answer (score 0):

**I Think its perfect in my way**

*Replace  ((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME) ADAPTER_CONTEXT) to activity so you get your Current Activity*

```
int id = currentCountry.getId();

Fragment mdf = new DetailsFragment();

((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME) ADAPTER_CONTEXT).getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragments_container, mdf)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

`View.getContext()` don't have to return `Context` of your `Activity`. It basically can be any `Context` that was used to inflate this view. In your case `Context` used to inflate view in your adapter is `ApplicationContext`. For quick fix you can change `Context` used in `onCreateViewHolder` method of your `RecyclerAdapter`. I am not sure how You inflate your recyclerview but maybe consider using `parent.getContext()` in `onCreateViewHolder`.

However it is much better to create callback in your adapter and delegate that click event to owner of your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but now I'm facing a new challenge: I need to pass the clicked item's data to the destination Fragment. Is there a way to make the callback you suggested return such data?

Comment: If you are using callback just add parameter to that function and pass your data :)

Comment: I tried. couldn't figure it out. If you think you can help, you can see my question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894651/how-to-pass-the-getadapterposion-value-back-to-the-calling-activity-through-ca?noredirect). Thanks.