# How to pass the item at the clicked position back to the Activity through callback methods

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to find how to return the clicked item to the ListActivity (in this Activity the list Adapter is instatiated). I get that item by using getAdapterPosition() method in the Adapter.

**ListActivity**

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListAdapter.ItemClickListener {

//some irrelevant code

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        adapter = new ListAdapter(context, this);

        adapter.setClickListener(this);

        //more irrelevant code
    }
}
```

**The callback code inside the Adapter class**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.RowViewHolder> {
// Adapter class code
...
    class RowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView viewName;
        ImageView viewFlag;
        LinearLayout countryEntry;

        RowViewHolder(View view) {

            super(view);
            viewName = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            countryEntry = view.findViewById(R.id.rowId);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            ListActivity.position = getAdapterPosition();
            final Country currentCountry = countriesList.get(getAdapterPosition());
            listActivity.setCurrentCountry(currentCountry);

        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
...
}
```

**The entire Adapter class** (in case you want to run it)

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.RowViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    FragmentManager fm;
    Activity listActivity;
    private Context context;
    private List<Country> countriesList;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, Activity listActivity) {

        this.fm = fm;
        this.listActivity = listActivity;
        this.context = context;
        countriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public RowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.row_list, parent,false);

//        context = parent.getContext();
        return new RowViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    class RowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView viewName;
        ImageView viewFlag;

        LinearLayout countryEntry;

        RowViewHolder(View view) {

            super(view);
            viewName = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewFlag = view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            countryEntry = view.findViewById(R.id.rowId);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            ListActivity.position = getAdapterPosition();
            final Country currentCountry = countriesList.get(getAdapterPosition());
//todo: can i return currentCountry to the listActivity in order to pass it?
        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull RowViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Country currentCountry = countriesList.get(position);
        int id = currentCountry.getId();

        holder.viewName.setText(countriesList.get(position).getName());

        Uri imageUrl = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(countriesList.get(position).getFlag()));

        SvgLoader.pluck()
                .with(listActivity)//Replace new MainActivity with activity
                .setPlaceHolder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .load(imageUrl, holder.viewFlag);

//        holder.viewFlag.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(countriesList.get(position).getFlag())));
//        holder.countryEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countriesList.size();
    }

    public void attachCountriesList(List<Country> countriesList) {
        // getting list from Fragment.
        this.countriesList = countriesList;
    }
}
```

The call from the Activity is `adapter.setClickListener(this);`. I've been trying to assign this call's result to an int variable but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything looks OK in the given code. What specific problems are you having in the `Activity`? Does it implement `ItemClickListener` properly? If everything compiles correctly and runs, how exactly are you determining that you're not getting the right value set?

Comment: The issue is that I couldn't find a way to pass the getAdapterPosion()'s result from the Adapter back to the Activity.

Comment: `ListActivity.position = getAdapterPosition();` this can't be right. You shouldn't need to communicate using statics. Isn't it part of the callback method arguments?

Comment: Are you asking whether the callback method returns the position? no. I need the country in the clicked position. I know how to set the country in the this position in the Adapter, but can't figure how to pass in to the Activity.

Comment: "The issue is that I couldn't find a way to pass the getAdapterPosion()'s result from the Adapter back to the Activity." – That's just restating what you said in the question. I'm asking for specific issues. Why exactly doesn't the interface you've implemented work?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you apparently got your answer there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: I did that before. I didn't get an answer, so it seemed that if the question is not new no one see it.