# ImageButton onclick listner inside ListView is not working. The App crashes after click

Tags: java, android, listview, button, imagebutton

I wrote following codes to make a call from inside the custom listView but whenever I press the Imagebutton the App crashes. I tried different articles and tutorials but could not make it happen. Could anybody see my codes and suggest how to do it?

**Xml of model listview**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EADEF1">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logobsca">
</de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#4527A0"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDesignation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"
    android:text="Designation"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#1F2020"
    android:textStyle="normal"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textPhone"
    android:layout_below="@id/textDesignation"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Phone"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#1F2020"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
    

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/callButton"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:clickable="false"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
         android:background="@drawable/roundcall"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Model Class Activity**

````
    ```public class ListMobileModel extends AppCompatActivity {
String Name;
String Designation;
String Phone;
ImageButton CallButton;
int Photo;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return Designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    Designation = designation;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public int getPhoto() {
    return Photo;
}

public void setPhoto(int photo) {
    Photo = photo;
}

public ListMobileModel(String name, String designation, String phone, int photo) {
    Name = name;
    Designation = designation;
    Phone = phone;
    Photo = photo;
}
````

}```

**ListView Adapter**

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListMobileModel> mobilelist;
ArrayList<ListMobileModel> arrayList;

public ListViewAdapter( Activity context, List<ListMobileModel> mobilelist) {

    context = context;
    this.mobilelist=mobilelist;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arrayList=new ArrayList<ListMobileModel>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(mobilelist);

}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView nameTV, designationTV, mobileTV;
    ImageView photoTV;
    ImageButton callButton;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobilelist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mobilelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listmobile_model, null);


        // locate the views in activity_listmobile_model.xml)

        holder.nameTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        holder.designationTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textDesignation);
        holder.mobileTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);
        holder.photoTV=view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        holder.callButton=view.findViewById(R.id.callButton);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
        //set the results into Textview
        holder.nameTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getName());
        holder.designationTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getDesignation());
        holder.mobileTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.photoTV.setImageResource(mobilelist.get(position).getPhoto());

        ImageButton callButton;
        callButton=view.findViewById(R.id.callButton);



        callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cellno=mobilelist.get(position).getPhone();
                Intent callIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + cellno));
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return;
                }
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
        return view;
}
//Filter
public void filter(String charText){
    charText=charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    mobilelist.clear();
    if(charText.length()==0){
        mobilelist.addAll(arrayList);
    }
    else{
        for(ListMobileModel row:arrayList){
            if (row.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)|| (row.getDesignation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))){
                mobilelist.add(row);
            }

        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}```

**List View Activity**

````
    ```public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListMobileModel> mobilelist;
ArrayList<ListMobileModel> arrayList;

public ListViewAdapter( Activity context, List<ListMobileModel> mobilelist) {

    context = context;
    this.mobilelist=mobilelist;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arrayList=new ArrayList<ListMobileModel>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(mobilelist);

}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView nameTV, designationTV, mobileTV;
    ImageView photoTV;
    ImageButton callButton;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobilelist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mobilelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listmobile_model, null);


        // locate the views in activity_listmobile_model.xml)

        holder.nameTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        holder.designationTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textDesignation);
        holder.mobileTV=view.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);
        holder.photoTV=view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        holder.callButton=view.findViewById(R.id.callButton);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
        //set the results into Textview
        holder.nameTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getName());
        holder.designationTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getDesignation());
        holder.mobileTV.setText(mobilelist.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.photoTV.setImageResource(mobilelist.get(position).getPhoto());

        ImageButton callButton;
        callButton=view.findViewById(R.id.callButton);



        callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cellno=mobilelist.get(position).getPhone();
                Intent callIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + cellno));
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    return;
                }
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
        return view;
}
//Filter
public void filter(String charText){
    charText=charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    mobilelist.clear();
    if(charText.length()==0){
        mobilelist.addAll(arrayList);
    }
    else{
        for(ListMobileModel row:arrayList){
            if (row.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)|| (row.getDesignation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))){
                mobilelist.add(row);
            }

        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
````

}```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjz5.jpg)``

Answer (score 0):

Using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`

`RecyclerView`'s Adapter and `ListView`'s Adapter are also the same.

[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example) here for more details.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Hasan for your input. My issue is with ImageButton click not with the ItemClick listener. My ItemClick listener is working fine.