# Retrieve Data from Child Node in Firebase and Display as TextView using Constructor Class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

UPDATE:
I have managed to retrieve specific dog data from my database (see `.child("moo")` below. I changed the push() element from my `SignUp` class so that the dogs name would be used as the ID instead of a unique ID. However if the user has more than one dog, what would be the best way to do this? How can I iterate through the specific dogs? How would I be able to display a specific dogs information?

---

I am trying to retrieve data from my Firebase database and display it within a `TextView`, I have done this elsewhere in my project without any issues but for some reason cannot retrieve my get/set methods from my constructor class. I am looking for some help figuring out why this is as I've been at it a few hours now and can't find a solution..

Basically I would like to retrieve the data from each unique individual dog under its user, and display it within the corresponding `TextView` element on my DogProfile class. This code is not working, it throws a NullObjectRef error but I really don't know how to fix this, I think I need to figure out how to access the current dog element? As if the user has more than one dog then it could be an issue..

My Firebase hiararchy:
[image]

Dog constructor:

```
public class Dog {
    private String name, breed, age, weight, gender, neutered;

    public Dog() {

    }

    public Dog (String name, String breed, String age, String weight, String gender, String neutered) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.neutered = neutered;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getWeight() { return weight; }

    public String getGender() { return gender; }

    public String getNeutered() { return neutered; }
}
```

Dog profile class:

```
   public class DogProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    TextView breed, age, dogGender, weight, isNeutered;
    String uid;
    String dogId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dog_profile);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = currentUser.getUid();

        breed = findViewById(R.id.breed);
        age = findViewById(R.id.age);
        dogGender = findViewById(R.id.gender);
        weight = findViewById(R.id.weight);
        isNeutered = findViewById(R.id.neutered);

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("user").child(uid).child("dogs");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String dogBreed = ds.child("breed").getValue(String.class);
                String dogAge = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                String gender = ds.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                String dogWeight = ds.child("weight").getValue(String.class);
                String neutered = ds.child("neutered").getValue(String.class);

                breed.setText(dogBreed);
                age.setText(dogAge);
                dogGender.setText(gender);
                weight.setText(dogWeight);
                isNeutered.setText(neutered);
            }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    
    
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".DogProfile">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="264dp"
        android:background="@color/olive"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="393dp"
        android:layout_height="560dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:autofillHints="age"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:hint="Age"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.085"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.353" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/weight"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:autofillHints="weight"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:hint="Weight (kg)"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.901"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.356" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breed"
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:autofillHints="breed"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="Breed"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.434"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.196" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="354dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:autofillHints="Name"
            android:background="@drawable/text_field"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032"></EditText>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:autofillHints="gender"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:hint="Gender"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/neutered"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:autofillHints="neutered"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:hint="Neutered?"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/name"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.901"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.535" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Daily Exercise Goal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.058"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.665" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.624" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You can't do that. Do you want to get specific dog or list of dogs?

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting the NullPointerException? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: put xml design code as well for me. I might provide some help.

Comment: Added XML @UjjwalJungThapa

Comment: @AlexMamo I think it was around the `addValueEventListener` - I have messed around since then so error is gone

Answer (score 1):

Since it is inside the list, I think you want to retrieve list of dogs. You need to use `for loop`.

```
    breedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String dogBreed;
            List<Dog> dogList;
             for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final Dog dog = snapshot.getValue(Dog.class);
                dogList.add(dog);
                dogBreed += dog.getBreed();
               
            }
            breed.setText(currentUser.getBreed());
            // -------------

            Log.i("TAG", dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would like to retrieve the specific details (breed, for example) of a particular dog under the current user. This seems straight forward for one dog, but itlf the user has more than one dog I need to get the particular dog whose details I am viewing - hope that makes sense! I am at work right now so I will play around with your answer after then :) Thanks!

Comment: @Caitlin the important one is you need to get its `dogUid`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I am not sure how to get to that point..

Comment: I do not wish to display the list of dogs, I would like to access each dog individually to retrieve details about them in order for the user (dog owner) to see and edit/update them.

Comment: what is `specificDog` referring to, I have an idea but can't get anything to work in its place

Comment: @Caitlin fixed the answer already. you can try. how do you want to retrieve details without listing the dogs?

Comment: On one page I would like to display the list of dogs, then each dog would have a button which would go to the dog profile page and display the details of the chosen dog. I don't understand how to achieve that

Comment: @Caitlin you either make a listview or using recyclerview to list out all the dogs. From there, you can make a button to view detail that specific dog

Comment: Okay, can I do this in a separate page or does it need to be in the same page?

Comment: it is up to you. @Caitlin which one is the best for you

Comment: I think the separate page would be best

Comment: @Caitlin https://stackoverflow.com/a/54655654/9346054 you can refer this to create recyclerview. if you still need help, Ticherhaz#7548 this is my discord