# How to add motion in Viewpager2?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

original Viewpager2 can scroll left&right to change page.
And I want to add "down to up scroll" to use 'startActivity'

I tried like this...but

```
Viewpager2 viewpager;
viewpager.getChildAt(0).setonTouchListener(new View.onTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
           return true;
     }
});
```

It cannot work original viewpager's left&right scroll.
I want to save original's, and add just another scroll.
How can i do?

#I searched about onInterceptTouchEvent, DispatchTouchEvent...
I cannot find how to use.

Answer (score 0):

you want vertical scroll to start new activity or to scroll through list items?
if you want to scroll through list then use recyclerView,see this - [Simple Android RecyclerView example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40584424/14778218)

and for starting new activity or any process on swiping(top to bottom or left to right)  see this - [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4139288/14778218)