# get array elements and assign it to textview in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have an array.
`["Type of Motor","Fan Size","Nominal Operating Voltage","Operating Voltage Range","Type of Blades","Fan Control Strategy","Protection Features"]`.
I want to convert this array to textview layout. I don't know how to do.

I want output like the image shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass this array in Recyclerview to show this data because we always use recyclerviews whenever we need to show a list content.
Here is the complete solution.
[Simple Android RecyclerView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)