# Add margins to divider in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

i am building an android app which is using `RecyclerView`. I want to add dividers to `RecyclerView`, which I did using this code:

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

So far everything works fine. However, the divider is taking the size of full screen and I want to add margins to it. Is there any way that I can add margins to the divider using a method that will add some space to the rectangle drawn and not by creating a custom drawable shape with margins and add it to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: use custom dividerItemDecoration

Comment: [See this answer. By far the best and easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434248/how-to-indent-the-divider-in-a-linear-layout-recyclerview-ie-add-padding-marg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this and customize according to your requirement.

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider};

    private Drawable divider;

    /**
     * Default divider will be used
     */
    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        divider = styledAttributes.getDrawable(0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Custom divider will be used
     */
    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int resId) {
        divider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + divider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            divider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            divider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case it's only showing once after the last item.

Answer (score 76):

I think the most straightforward solution is to use the setDrawable method on the Decoration object and pass it an inset drawable with the inset values you want for the margins. Like so:

```
int[] ATTRS = new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider};

TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
Drawable divider = a.getDrawable(0);
int inset = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_margin_value);
InsetDrawable insetDivider = new InsetDrawable(divider, inset, 0, inset, 0);
a.recycle();

DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
itemDecoration.setDrawable(insetDivider);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

Comment: Genious! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simply correct answer. Do not implement your own ItemDecoration if you can reuse and modify the existing one.

Comment: I'm getting OOM when calling `obtainStyledAttributes`. I'm using kotlin

Comment: How could I set a height to this divider so it can be thicker?

Comment: @On_my_way_to_Dev_Life You would probably have to modify the source drawable to make it thicker.

Comment: Best and minimal solution.

Comment: Great answer, but `InsetDrawable` requires API level 26+

Comment: It doesn't require min API 26, works just fine

Answer (score 21):

**shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#E6E7F0" />
    <size android:height="1dp" />
</shape>
```

**layer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp" />

</layer-list>
```

**Code**

```
val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
itemDecoration.setDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.layer, null))
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
```

Comment: This is the most simple solution to add margin of the divider in recycler view.

Comment: no need for layer~ Just use inset：https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434249/5093308

Answer (score 7):

Elaborating on @SeptimusX75: if you (like me) prefer to do UI stuff in XML you can create an inset drawable file. You'll have to create a second XML file but since in return your code gets cleaner I say it's worth it :-).

[UPDATE] as user @Zhou Hongbo suggest in the comments, using only one XML file: **divider.xml**:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/divider_base"
    android:insetRight="20dp"
    android:insetLeft="20dp">

    <shape>
        <android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:height="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/dividerColor" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

[OLD ANSWER]:

**divider_base.xml** *(the actual divider)*:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/dividerColor" />
</shape>
```

**divider.xml** *(the inset)*:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/divider_base"
    android:insetRight="20dp"
    android:insetLeft="20dp">
</inset>
```

Comment: These two files can be combined~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434249/5093308

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own item decoration for recycler view.
Here is code for the same.

```
public class SimpleItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    int space;
    boolean isHorizontalLayout;
    public SimpleItemDecorator(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    public SimpleItemDecorator(int space, boolean isHorizontalLayout) {
        this.space = space;
        this.isHorizontalLayout = isHorizontalLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        if(isHorizontalLayout)
        {
            outRect.bottom=space;
            outRect.right=space;
            outRect.left=space;
            outRect.top=space;

        } else {
            outRect.bottom = space;
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
                outRect.top = space;
            else
                outRect.top = 0;

        }


    }
}
```

And to use it with your recyclerview you can do like this:

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleItemDecorator(5));
```

Comment: Ok...And how it will draw anything? There are no divider in that snippet

Comment: @Sever it's adding space not drawing anything.

Answer (score 4):

I found the best and simplest solution

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="40dp"
       android:insetRight="40dp" >
    <shape>
        <size android:height="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/recyclerview_divider" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434249/5093308

Answer (score 3):

Same like @Vivek answer but in Kotlin and different params

```
class SimpleItemDecorator : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private var top_bottom: Int = 0
    private var left_right: Int = 0

    /**
     * @param top_bottom for top and bottom margin
     * @param left_right for left and right margin
     */
    constructor(top_bottom: Int, left_right: Int = 0) {
        this.top_bottom = top_bottom
        this.left_right = left_right
    }

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        outRect.bottom = top_bottom
        outRect.top = top_bottom
        outRect.right = left_right
        outRect.left = left_right
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple `Kotlin` code snippet to implement `ItemDecoration` with `RecyclerView`:

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
                override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
                    outRect.left = 20    // Left Margin.
                    outRect.right = 20   // Right Margin.
                    outRect.top = 16     // Top Margin.
                    outRect.bottom = 16  // Bottom Margin.
                }
            })
```

**Explantation**:- In the above example code, we are adding margins to each item of
RecyclerView from all four directions.

*Happy Coding...*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for divider in `RecyclerView` with left margin. Just paste the code in your `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`.

```
class SimpleDividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public SimpleDividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        mDivider = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = 250;
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(
            getApplicationContext()));
```

Since, the `divider.xml` file will be missing from your drawable folder so below is the code that you have to paste on the divider layout after creating it on drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <size
    android:width="1dp"
    android:height="1dp" />

  <solid android:color="@color/divider" />

</shape>
```