# How to make DividerItemDecoration in RecyclerView not take up the full width of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My question is similar to this one, however I don't want to set margins.

[Add margins to divider in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546983/add-margins-to-divider-in-recyclerview)

I'm setting the divider in a Fragment. I'm not creating a separate DividerItemDecoration class and then referencing it in a Fragment. I just have these two lines:

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(newDividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Can I modify this code somehow? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `DividerItemDecoration#setDrawable(Drawable drawable)` method and pass `InsetDrawable` as a parameter

Comment: Could it be done without passing InsetDrawable?

Comment: sure: create your custom `Drawable` class, but why if you can just use `InsetDrawable`?