# How to add vertical margin around divider between RecyclerView items in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, divider, item-decoration

This is my custom Item Decoration class: **DividerItemDecorator.kt**

```
class DividerItemDecorator(private val mDivider: Drawable) : ItemDecoration() {

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val dividerLeft = parent.paddingLeft
        val dividerRight = parent.width - parent.paddingRight

        val childCount = parent.childCount
        for (i in 0..childCount - 2) {
            val child: View = parent.getChildAt(i)

            val params = child.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams

            val dividerTop: Int = child.bottom + params.bottomMargin
            val dividerBottom = dividerTop + mDivider.intrinsicHeight

            mDivider.setBounds(dividerLeft, dividerTop, dividerRight, dividerBottom)
            mDivider.draw(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I add my custom Item Decoration to my recyclerView:

```
subNodeBody.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecorator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context,
                R.drawable.recyclerview_divider)!!))
subNodeBody.adapter = RolesAdapter(subNode.roles)
```

This is the divider drawable: **recyclerview_divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#e7eef3"/>
    <size android:height="0.7dp"/>
    <size android:width="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

The divider looks proper between the RecyclerView items. But there's no space above and below it. Is there a way to add custom margins(top, bottom, right and left) around custom dividers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546983/add-margins-to-divider-in-recyclerview Refer this similar question

Comment: @Astha that question is for horizontal margins... what I am looking for is vertical margins